# Cannot pull with git

Tags: git, merge, branch, pull

We have a branch in our git repo called `feature/TestBapi`.

I created a new remote connection to repository `MyRepoA` : `git remote add repo-A-branch ../MyRepoA`

When i do `git pull repo-A-branch feature/TestBapi --allow-unrelated-histories` i get :

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref feature/TestBapi
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

In my git config, i have :

```
branch.feature/TestBapi.remote=origin
branch.feature/TestBapi.merge=refs/heads/feature/TestBapi
```

To verify the existence of my branch, i did : `git checkout --track origin/feature/TestBapi`. I get : `fatal: A branch named 'feature/TestBapi' already exists.`

I am stumped here. Any ideas?

Comment: I see where you've verified that the branch exists in origin and in your local repo.  Where have you verified that it exists in `MyRepoA`?

Comment: no in an other repository `MyRepoB`

Comment: What does `git remote show repo-A-branch` say?

Comment: @Christoph here is the result of your command : `* remote repo-A-Branch
  Fetch URL: ../MyRepoA
  Push  URL: ../MyRepoA
  HEAD branch: feature/dev
  Remote branches:
    feature/dev tracked
    master            tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)`

Comment: So there is no branch `feature/TestBapi`!?

Comment: @Christoph i'm in `MyRepoB` where the branch `feature/TestBapi` existing. The `repo-A-branch` is a remote from `MyBranchA`. But when i do `git remote show origin` i see my branch : `Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    feature/TestBapi merges with remote feature/TestBapi
    master           merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    feature/TestBapi pushes to feature/TestBapi (up to date)
    master           pushes to master           (up to date)`

Comment: So `git pull repo-A-branch feature/TestBapi`does not work wheras `git pull origin feature/TestBapi`does?

Comment: @Christoph thanks for your suggestions ! i find the problem.  i should doing `git pull repo-A-branch branch-of-MyRepoA --allow-unrelated-histories` and not `git pull repo-A-branch feature/TestBapi --allow-unrelated-histories` because `feature/TestBapi` is into `MyRepoB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
git pull repo-A-branch feature/TestBapi --allow-unrelated-histories
```

that means "on `repo-A-branch` (which you've mapped to `../myRepoA`), find the branch named `feature/TestBapi`; fetch it; and merge the result into my current branch.

As pointed out in multiple ways in the comments, the branch does not exist in `../myRepoA`.

When this is pointed out, you reply that the branch exists in the local repo, and/or that it exists at `origin`.  Which is fine, but it doesn't change the fact that it *doesn't* exist in the repo where you're telling git to look for it.

Perhaps you need to take a step back and review why you're trying to run this command.  What are you expecting it to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for this explication ! i find the solution by understanding what you said. i should doing `git pull repo-A-branch branch-of-MyRepoA --allow-unrelated-histories` and not `git pull repo-A-branch feature/TestBapi --allow-unrelated-histories` because `feature/TestBapi` is into `MyRepoB`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry but maybe it was a typing error by someone